# CMS or Framework for a new project

Tags: php, frameworks, content-management-system

This may be a wrong section of StackExchange for this, but it's about programming so I thought this would be a good place to start.

I have been asked to look into a new system and to upgrade our current system too.

We are currently running Drupal 6.x but as this is getting old now and we wish to expand, we need a more up-to-date CMS. I have been told to keep an open mind about writing a custom CMS from scratch or using a framework.

The key things that I see needed in a CMS are the following:

```
1. Good URL routing system.
2. A nice templating system (like PHPBB's or simular to smarty).
3. Database driven (obviously), but it can be MySQL, MongoDB (NoSQL) etc.
4. Easy to administer.
5. Easy to customise (styles and modules/plugins).
6. A good community for the CMS (a plus not a necessity).
7. RESTful API would be a plus too.
8. Security is paramount.
```

However, I have done my research, and I do not want to go down the route of Joomla! and to be honest I don't want to wait for Drupal 8 (we have also dismissed Drupal 7 as it was too bloated and didn't do what we wanted).

On the other hand, if you know of any frameworks that provide most of these features then I am open to all suggestions as I am quite content with writing one from a framework base.

So please let me know what anyone thinks.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want a free or paid-for solution ...?

Comment: How about Wordpress? It should meet all your needs (not sure about restful api)

Comment: I am open for a paid solution, but obviously open source is always a plus. And WordPress is barely a CMS it is an advanced blogging system. Thanks for the idea though

Comment: @DarkMantis, depends on how you configure it though.

Comment: If I add too many specifics it will become too custom and I won't get a straight answer. I just want to know what people think of CMS's which have the list of features that I have specified

Comment: Check out this? http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-popular-content-management-systems-online/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you want a cms or a framework?

1. for a framework - codeigniter is pretty good.has most of the things you need, only the template system uses directly php
2. if it's a CMS you want - wordpress ... maybe

my advice, if you want smth too specific, and optimized for you needs, go for a framework and write your own CMS, that will be compliant with your need at a 100%

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using WordPress - you can customize it to your hearts content, and if you're looking for a specific functionality, chances are you will find a plugin for it with a single google search.

If you are writing a theme from scratch, consider using the excelent [Skeleton Grid](http://getskeleton.com) system, for responsive design. It has made my life easier.

Comment: My team have already thought about WordPress and we came to the conclusion it doesn't do what we want really, as it is designed for being a blogging software

Comment: It **was** designed to be a blogging software, but over time it has matured into a fully fledged CMS. :)